# How to prove $(I+A)^{-1} = I - \left(\frac{1}{1 + \mbox{tr}(A)}\right) A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do we prove the following?

$$(I+A)^{-1} = I - \left(\frac{1}{1 + \mbox{tr}(A)}\right) A$$

---

I tried letting

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{12} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} $$

and then rearranging for $(I+A)^{-1}$ and equating it to the right hand side but they didn't equate. Please let me know if there's a more efficient method.

Comment: This formula is only true if $\operatorname{rank}(A)={\tt1}.\;$ It is called the _Sherman-Morrison_ formula. For the general $2\times 2$ case, see my post below.

Comment: @greg It is also true when $A=0$.

Answer (score 3):

The equality seems untrue by letting $A=I$, then LHS$=I/2$ but RHS$=2I/3$.

Comment: Multiplying the Matrix $(I+A)$ by the **"Purported"** Inverse will not give $I$ , which again shows that the Original Claim was not true !

Answer (score 0):

If $\:X\in{\mathbb C}^{2\times 2}\,$ then
$$\eqalign{
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\X{X^{-1}}
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1#2{\c{\fracLR{#1}{#2}}}
&0 = X^2 - X\tr(X) + I\det(X) \\
&0 = X - I\tr(X) + \X\,\c{\det(X)} \\
&0 = X - I\tr(X) + \X\CLR{\bR{\tr(X)}^2 - \tr\LR{X^2}}{2} \\
&\X = \frac{2\BR{I\tr(X) - X}}{\BR{\tr(X)}^2 - \tr\LR{X^2}}  \\
}$$
Substituting the variables
$$\eqalign{
\a &= \tr(A),\qquad \b = \tr(A^2),\qquad \l &= \fracLR{\a^2-\b}2 \\
 X &= \bR{I+A} \\
}$$
yields these handy formulas
$$\eqalign{
A^{-1} &= \fracLR{\a I-A}{\l} \\
\bR{I+A}^{-1} &= \LR{I-\frac{A}{\o+\a}}\fracLR{\o+\a}{\o+\a+\l}  \\
}$$
The latter is close to the desired formula, except for the final scaling factor.

That final factor is unity when $\l=0$ which occurs when $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le\o$.